# Class cast exception on java ouaf

Tags: java, exception, casting

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.splwg.ccb.domain.fieldorder.fieldActivity.entity.FieldActivity_Id
>   cannot be cast to com.splwg.base.api.QueryResultRow   at
>   com.splwg.cm.domain.meterread.batch.CmCompleteReadOnlyFAsBatch.getJobWork(CmCompleteReadOnlyFAsBatch.java:115)

I got the following errors from the logs. Any idea how to fix this? Here's the specific code where the error was found.

```
    List<QueryResultRow> fieldActivities = retrieveFieldActivities ();
    List<ThreadWorkUnit> workUnits = new ArrayList<ThreadWorkUnit>();
            ThreadWorkUnit workUnit = null;
            for(QueryResultRow row : fieldActivities) {
                FieldActivity_Id faId = (FieldActivity_Id) row.getId("id", FieldActivity.class);
                workUnit = new ThreadWorkUnit();
                workUnit.setPrimaryId(faId);
                workUnits.add(workUnit);
            }
    return createJobWorkForThreadWorkUnitList (workUnits);

private List<QueryResultRow> retrieveFieldActivities () {

        StringBuffer queryStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        queryStringBuffer.append(" FROM FieldActivity as fa, FieldActivityCharacteristic as fac");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" WHERE fa.fieldActivityType = :faTypesForQuery");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" AND fa.fieldActivityStatus = :faStatusFlg");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" AND fa.id = fac.id.fieldActivity");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" AND fac.id.characteristicType = :readReqCharType");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" AND NOT EXISTS (");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" SELECT fa.id");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" FROM FieldActivityCharacteristic as fac, FieldActivity as fa");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" WHERE fac.id.fieldActivity = fa.id");
        queryStringBuffer.append(" AND fac.id.characteristicType = :readPostCharType)");

        Query<QueryResultRow> fieldActivityQuery = createQuery(
                queryStringBuffer.toString(), "fieldActivityQuery");

        FieldActivityType_Id fieldActTypeForQueryId = new FieldActivityType_Id(fieldActTypesForQuery);

        fieldActivityQuery.bindId("faTypesForQuery", fieldActTypeForQueryId);
        fieldActivityQuery.bindLookup("faStatusFlg", pendingStatus);
        fieldActivityQuery.bindId("readReqCharType", readRequestedCharType);
        fieldActivityQuery.bindId("readPostCharType", readPostedCharType);

        fieldActivityQuery.addResult("fieldAct", "fa.id");

        logger.info("faTypesForQuery:" + fieldActTypeForQueryId);
        logger.info("faStatusFlg:" + pendingStatus);
        logger.info("readReqCharType:" + readRequestedCharType);
        logger.info("readPostCharType:" + readPostedCharType);

        List<QueryResultRow> fieldActivityRows = fieldActivityQuery.list();

        return fieldActivityRows;       
    }
```

`for(QueryResultRow row : fieldActivities)` is line 115!

Comment: This is strange. Can you tell us what `retrieveFieldActivities()` is actually returning? Assuming that this list is really of the correct type, that for-each should not throw such an exception.

Comment: Here's the method and it's return type:

private List<QueryResultRow> retrieveFieldActivities () {
      **some HQL queries here to retrieve field activity ids**
       List<QueryResultRow> fieldActivityRows = fieldActivityQuery.list();
       return fieldActivityRows;  
 }

Comment: Don't put it into comments. Edit your question to contain a true [mcve] please.

Comment: Just added the method